# Get only lines that are changed

Tags: regex, grep

I have text that contains many similar lines.

```
line1
line1
line1
line1
line2
line2
line2
line2
line1
```

I need to extract only these lines that that are changed (previous line and current is different). What regular expression I should pass to `grep` to extract lines:

```
line1
line2
line1
```

Comment: Changed *from what*?

Comment: previous line and current is different

Comment: Why do you even need regex for this? Just read the file line by line and compare

Answer (score 3):

You want `uniq`:

```
$ uniq infile
line1
line2
line1
```